# How to change MIME type of the JS file that is received?

Tags: javascript, module

When I am trying to import JS file "/assets/js/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload/src/adapters/simpleuploadadapter" I get the error:

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

As I have understood I need to add MIME type for the directory where the JS file is contained. Can I do it in htaccess?

```
<script type="module">
    import SimpleUploadAdapter from '/assets/js/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload/src/adapters/simpleuploadadapter';

    ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
            plugins: [ SimpleUploadAdapter],
            toolbar: [],
            simpleUpload: {
                // The URL that the images are uploaded to.
                uploadUrl: 'http://example.com',

                // Enable the XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials property.
                withCredentials: true,

                // Headers sent along with the XMLHttpRequest to the upload server.
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 'CSRF-Token',
                    Authorization: 'Bearer <JSON Web Token>'
                }
            }
        } )
        .then( )
        .catch( );
</script>
```

I used the function shown below to know mime type. result - text/x-c++

```
<?php echo mime_content_type($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/assets/js/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload/src/adapters/simpleuploadadapter.js') ?>
```

Comment: Add `.js` to the filename, that should make the webserver return the correct MIME type.

Comment: Yep, @Barmar is probably right. You're importing from `/assets/js/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload/src/adapters/simpleuploadadapter`, but should be pointing to `/assets/js/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload/src/adapters/simpleuploadadapter.js`. You may be seeing the result of trying to load the webserver's error page.

Comment: @Barmar, When i add .js i get different error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "assets/js/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: Sounds like you removed the `/` at the beginning as well. Don't do that.

Comment: @Barmar, No( This code i added  import SimpleUploadAdapter from '/assets/js/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload/src/adapters/simpleuploadadapter.js';

Comment: @Barmar, In ckeditor5 JS files are imported without .js